# `Errno::EExist` error with sprockets when running rails in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, assets, sprockets

This has happened to me on multiple occassions now and I was hoping someone could provide some insight into the the following error:

> Errno::EEXIST at / 
>   File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/Pd

Here's the associated stack trace:

```
Errno::EEXIST - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/dev/keithgw-dev/code/myapp/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/Pd:
() opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `fu_mkdir'
() opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
() opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block in mkdir_p'
() opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `mkdir_p'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:85:in `set'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/cache.rb:212:in `set'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/cache.rb:136:in `set'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:321:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
sprockets (3.6.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:49:in `precompiled_assets'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:34:in `asset_precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:214:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:345:in `precompiled?'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:349:in `raise_unless_precompiled_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:334:in `find_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:216:in `block in lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:229:in `block in resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:228:in `resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:215:in `lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:157:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
sprockets-rails (3.0.4) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:156:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
() home/dev/keithgw-dev/code/myapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3086746537636264556_24830040'
```

It appears it's failing to create a random subdirectory in `tmp/cache` in order to cache the on the fly compiled assets (I'm running in `development` mode). However, the directory shown in the error message does *not* exist.

Clearing the temp cache and restarting rails doesn't resolve the issue. The only way I've been able to get around this is to start another rails application on the same system somewhere else. After that comes up, I kill it and restart the failing app and it works again. There's no real evidence to suggest that's an actual work around or if it's just a coincidence.

Anyways, I would love to hear from anyone else who has experienced this before or if someone might be able to shed some light on why this is happening.

Thanks.

- Rails - 4.2.6
- Ruby - 2.2.2

Comment: I'm having this problem right now on a fresh clone of a project that's works  fine on my other machine.  I have no more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently my Google-fu is strong today.  I found a ticket filed against Sprockets 3.6.0 that relates to case-insensitive filesystems.  See https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/283

(This is my case, anyway, running vagrant on a Windows host)

Regretfully, it seems that the maintainers of the project are still discussing a fix.

Comment: Strong google-fu indeed. Turns out this was it. Even though I'm working in a Linux environment, my home directory is mounted from a windows share so I'm still subject to case-insensitive file names. Rolling back sprockets worked, but I'm considering moving my work to a locally mounted volume. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try deleting the `tmp` folder, creating it somewhere in the host and linking it.

```
rm -rf tmp
mkdir /tmp/rails-app
ln -s /tmp/rails-app tmp
```